# Powershell - Windows forms - script calling another script, 2nd script modifying form elements

Tags: powershell, graphical-user-interface

I'm developing a Powershell script that's going to present the user with a GUI.  When the user presses a button in the GUI, I want it to call, (execute), a 2nd powershell script, the 2nd script will do some things, and then modify form elements in the GUI, (Like a CheckedListBox), that the first script created.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault are supposed to relate to system and network administration. If you can update your question to clearly show that it is related to these fields it may be reopened. Otherwise please use [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) for general programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

As for the GUI and running the second script part yes it is possible.  It will require working with .NET classes, specifically System.Windows.Forms as well as sub-classes below that.  I'm not really in a position to explain the finer details of passing information back and forth between the two scripts, assuming it's possible outside of storing that information in a separate file and using something like $varible=Get-Content "\path_of_file\".

However what you gave is a little broad and hard to give more specific examples for.